# Piping command line

Tags: python

I'm using in2csv to convert a folder of .xls to .txt files using python subprocess module.

```
 for filename in os.listdir(raw_data_folder):

    full_filename = raw_data_folder + '\\' + filename
    new_name = filename.split('.')
    new_name = new_name[0] + str('.txt')
    new_name = raw_data_folder + new_name
    process_call = 'in2csv "' + full_filename + '" > "' + new_name + '"'
    subprocess.call(process_call)
```

I keep getting non-zero exit status 2, while it says unrecognized arguments : > (new_name). How do you pipe that input to an output file?

Comment: `shlex.split` your argument string before using `subprocess.call`

Comment: Please rephrase as an actual question.

Comment: problem was solved, issue with tabs and spaces in my text editor. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1):

The redirection operator '>' is processed by the shell, so you have to tell `call` that you want it to use the shell:

```
subprocess.call(process_call, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest giving [`envoy`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/envoy) a try. It's just a small wrapper around `subprocess` which exposes a much nicer API that makes piping quite simple and intuitive.

But if that's all you're doing, then you should print out `process_call` and try debugging from there. I can't see an obvious reason your code isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

as Hiroto suggested, use the [`shlex.split`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) functionality

```
>>> import shlex, subprocess
>>> command_line = raw_input()
/bin/vikings -input eggs.txt -output "spam spam.txt" -cmd "echo '$MONEY'"
>>> args = shlex.split(command_line)
>>> print args
['/bin/vikings', '-input', 'eggs.txt', '-output', 'spam spam.txt', '-cmd', "echo '$MONEY'"]
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(args) # Success!
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Tab and space problems in my code editor. Thank you all.